# Mysql Query which returns SNo along with Group By

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am looking for MySQL Query which Returns Sno along with Rows. Please note the query uses group by functionality.

Please Note the query below .It doesnt work for group by functionality

```
SELECT @rownum:= @rownum+1 AS Sno
  FROM tableName, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r;
```

Could someone please explain why I get error when is don't put `r` at the end of above query?

Comment: You need some table name to store the data from `(SELECT @rownum:=0)`. And that's the reason! :)

Answer (score 0):

`(SELECT @rownum:=0)` is a derived table and it must be given aliasin MySQL otherwise it will throw an error. try this:

```
SET @rownum = 0;

SELECT (@rownum:= @rownum + 1) AS Sno 
FROM tableName;
```